# io.WriteSeeker and io.ReadSeeker from []byte or file

Tags: file-io, go, buffer

I have a method called "DoSomething".  DoSomething will take binary source data perform an operation on it, and write out binary data.  DoSomething needs to be generic enough to handle either a []byte array or a file handle for both the source and destination.  To accomplish this, I have attempted to declare the method like this:

`func DoSomething(source *io.ReadSeeker, destination *io.WriteSeeker)`

I have implemented the ReadSeeker and WriteSeeker for working with buffers, using my own custom, required methods (if there is a way to automatically accomplish this, I'd love to hear about it as well). 
Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to create either an io.ReadSeeker or io.WriteSeeker from a file handle.  I'm fairly sure there must be some pre-cooked way of handling this without having to manually implement them.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A file already implements both of those. You can do something like this:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "io"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   f, err := os.Open("test.txt")
   if err != nil {
     fmt.Println(err)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   f2, err := os.Create("test2.txt")
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
   }
   defer f2.Close()
   DoSomething(f, f2) 
}

func DoSomething(source io.ReadSeeker, destination io.WriteSeeker) {
   io.Copy(destination, source)
}
```

Also, you don't need to pass pointers to interfaces, which makes it easier to deal with them.

Comment: Thanks!  That should have been obvious.

Can I create a ReadSeeker/WriteSeeker, from a []byte buffer without manually implementing all the methods?

Comment: I thought the `bytes.Buffer` package would handle it, but apparently not. Search the google group for posts on seeker and bytes. So, yeah, you'd probably need to wrap it in something that implements `Seek` if you really need that.

Comment: I wrote a package that does exactly what you're looking for. The new structure is backed by a `bytes.Buffer` and implements `io.Reader`, `io.Seeker`, `io.ReaderAt`, `io.Writer` etc.. The main purpose of the pkg is to avoid having to use a file (temporary or not) when the data doesn't need to be persisted. Here is the pkg: https://github.com/mattetti/filebuffer

Comment: If something wants `io.ReadSeeker`, `bytes.NewReader` is probably exactly what you need.

Answer (score 9):

For anyone else who needs to accomplish something like this, here's what I ended up with.  It isn't complete, but it is close enough for what I needed:

```
package filebuffer

import (
    "bytes"
    "errors"
)

type FileBuffer struct {
    Buffer bytes.Buffer
    Index  int64
}

func NewFileBuffer() FileBuffer {
    return FileBuffer{}
}

func (fbuffer *FileBuffer) Bytes() []byte {
    return fbuffer.Buffer.Bytes()
}

func (fbuffer *FileBuffer) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := bytes.NewBuffer(fbuffer.Buffer.Bytes()[fbuffer.Index:]).Read(p)

    if err == nil {
        if fbuffer.Index+int64(len(p)) < int64(fbuffer.Buffer.Len()) {
            fbuffer.Index += int64(len(p))
        } else {
            fbuffer.Index = int64(fbuffer.Buffer.Len())
        }
    }

    return n, err
}

func (fbuffer *FileBuffer) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := fbuffer.Buffer.Write(p)

    if err == nil {
        fbuffer.Index = int64(fbuffer.Buffer.Len())
    }

    return n, err
}

func (fbuffer *FileBuffer) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (int64, error) {
    var err error
    var Index int64 = 0

    switch whence {
    case 0:
        if offset >= int64(fbuffer.Buffer.Len()) || offset < 0 {
            err = errors.New("Invalid Offset.")
        } else {
            fbuffer.Index = offset
            Index = offset
        }
    default:
        err = errors.New("Unsupported Seek Method.")
    }

    return Index, err
}
```

You then use it like this:

```
destination := filebuffer.NewFileBuffer()

source, err := os.Open(pathString)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer source.Close()

if _, err := encrypter.Decrypt(source, &destination, password); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

Comment: Beware, this doesn't support io.SeekCurrent, io.SeekEnd, nor seeking to EOF.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs it, here's an implementation of io.ReadWriteSeeker, that supports all I/O operations:

```golang
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

// Implements io.ReadWriteSeeker for testing purposes.
type FileBuffer struct {
    buffer []byte
    offset int64
}

// Creates new buffer that implements io.ReadWriteSeeker for testing purposes.
func NewFileBuffer(initial []byte) FileBuffer {
    if initial == nil {
        initial = make([]byte, 0, 100)
    }
    return FileBuffer{
        buffer: initial,
        offset: 0,
    }
}

func (fb *FileBuffer) Bytes() []byte {
    return fb.buffer
}

func (fb *FileBuffer) Len() int {
    return len(fb.buffer)
}

func (fb *FileBuffer) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    available := len(fb.buffer) - int(fb.offset)
    if available == 0 {
        return 0, io.EOF
    }
    size := len(b)
    if size > available {
        size = available
    }
    copy(b, fb.buffer[fb.offset:fb.offset+int64(size)])
    fb.offset += int64(size)
    return size, nil
}

func (fb *FileBuffer) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    copied := copy(fb.buffer[fb.offset:], b)
    if copied < len(b) {
        fb.buffer = append(fb.buffer, b[copied:]...)
    }
    fb.offset += int64(len(b))
    return len(b), nil
}

func (fb *FileBuffer) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (int64, error) {
    var newOffset int64
    switch whence {
    case io.SeekStart:
        newOffset = offset
    case io.SeekCurrent:
        newOffset = fb.offset + offset
    case io.SeekEnd:
        newOffset = int64(len(fb.buffer)) + offset
    default:
        return 0, errors.New("Unknown Seek Method")
    }
    if newOffset > int64(len(fb.buffer)) || newOffset < 0 {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("Invalid Offset %d", offset)
    }
    fb.offset = newOffset
    return newOffset, nil
}
```